# ASR failback fails because boot type UEFI

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, failover

Our on-premises environment is VMware running Windows Server virtual machines. We are using Azure Site Recovery (ASR) to replicate some of our VMs to Azure. I have been doing some failover/failback testing and I have run into an issue.

On one VM that has been in ASR for at least a couple years, I successfully failed over to Azure and failed back to on-prem.
On two other newer VMs (one is WS2016; the other is WS2019) that I added to ASR just recently in order to test failover/backback, failing over was successful, but failing back generates this error:

`Reprotect and Failback is not supported for the virtual machine (myvirtmachine) because it has boot type UEFI.`

For all 3 of the machines I tested (including the one that successfully failed back), VMware > Settings > VM Options > Boot Options are identical. (Including Firmware=EFI; Secure Boot=Disabled)

Is there somewhere that I can change the boot type so that these machines will fail back? Or, is there something I should do with the settings in VMware *before* I fail over so that the machine will fail back?

Answer (score 0):

This [Update Rollup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4531426/update-rollup-42-for-azure-site-recovery) says it should be supported, but there are prerequisites, make sure you are up to date. Also this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-physical-azure-support-matrix) shows a lot of things about prerequisites about Azure Site Recovery / VM replication supported.

**Prerequisites**

- Microsoft Azure Site Recovery Provider (version 5.1.4800 or a later version)
- Microsoft Azure Site Recovery Unified Setup (VMware to Azure) (version 9.26.xxxx.x or a later version)
- Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent (version 2.0.8700.0 or a later version)

**Improvements**

- Azure Site Recovery now supports test failover, failover & failback of VMware and Azure machines with UEFI layout
- VMware machines with following operating systems are supported - Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012R2, Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2019, SLES12Sp4, RHEL8
- All Azure machines that are Generation 2 are supported

Usually when a task fails, it shows Cause / Problem (like you posted on your question) and Solution (there are possible solution and link to a page).

This [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-reprotect#before-you-begin) is a good one for limitations when you try a failback.

For more troubleshooting you should read this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-troubleshoot-failback-reprotect).

In case that it won't help, please consider to open a ticket to Microsoft, they can see what is happening behind the scene.

Comment: This was helpful. It turned out that the problem was autodeployment of Site Recovery Mobility Service was not working and the VM was running an old version. When I installed the newest version from the configuration server, the Re-protect operation no longer complained about UEFI.